# Query running in PHPmyadmin but not through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to run a query from PHP which is not running but I can run the query from within phpMyAdmin

here is the code

```
<?php
   ob_start();
//Delete Item question to admin and delete product

include"../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";

$conn = mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass","$db_name") or die ("could not connect to mysql");

if (isset($_GET['deleteid'])) {
    echo 'Do you really want to delete the item with ID '.$_GET['deleteid'].' ?<a href="inventory_list.php?yesdelete='.$_GET['deleteid'].'">Yes</a>|<a href="inventory_list.php">No</a>';
    exit();
    } 

if(isset($_GET['yesdelete'])){

    // Delete the actual product and delete picture also
    //delete from database
    $id_to_delete = $_GET['yesdelete'];
    $manager=preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_GET['yesdelete']);
     //$sql=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username = '$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1 ");


    $sql = mysql_query( $conn ,"DELETE FROM products WHERE id=`$id_to_delete` LIMIT 1 ") or (mysql_error());
    //echo 'The data at number ' . $id_to_delete . ' Deleted Sucessfully';



    //mysqli_query("DELETE * FROM products WHERE id=`$id_to_delete`LIMIT1");// or (mysql_error());

    //Unlink file from server
    $pictodelete=("../inventory_images/$id_to_delete");
    //echo $pictodelete;
    if(file_exists($pictodelete)){
        unlink($pictodelete);
        }

    //  header("location:inventory_list.php");
        //exit();

    }   

?>
```

I am new to PHP so your help is sought, i am able to connect to to database at another instance the code of which is following

```
    <?php 

//checking the user
ob_start();
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["manager"])){
    header ("location:admin_login.php");
exit();
}  
//be sure to check if this manager SESSION value is in the database
$managerID=preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["id"]);
$manager=preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["manager"]);
$password=preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["password"]);
//runMYSQL query to assertain that this is manager
//Connect to mysql database
include"../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT*FROM admin WHERE id='$managerID' AND username='$manager' AND password='$password'LIMIT 1");
// make sure person exists in database
$existCount=mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($existCount== 0)
{
    echo "your data do not match our records";
exit();
    }

?>
```

The code in connect_to_my_sql.php is as follows

```
    <?php
/*
1: "die()" will exit the script and show an error statement if something goes wrong with the "connect" or "select" functions.
2: A "mysql_connect()" error usually means your username/password are wrong
3: A "mysql_select_db()" error usually means that the database does not exist
*/
// Place db host name Sometimes "localhost" but
// sometimes looks like this:>> ???mysql??.someserver.net

$db_host = "localhost";
//Place the username for the MySQL database here
$db_username = "storeuser";
//Place the password for the MySQL database here
$db_pass = "rajjar";
//Place the name for the MySQL database here
$db_name="mystore";

// Run the actual connection here
$conn = mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass","$db_name") or die ("could not connect to mysql");
//mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("no database");
?>
```

Comment: If you are using PHPMyAdmin surely you have PHP installed?

Comment: `id=\`$id_to_delete\`` Backticks should be quotes.... this shouldn't work in phpmyadmin either

Comment: However, you'd be well advised to start learning about prepared statements/bind variables with MySQLi or PDO rather than working with the old, deprecated MySQL extension that is officially scheduled to die before the end of this year

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: And seriously? `$password=preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["password"]);`

Comment: sorry mark for preg_replace but that was done in frustation

Comment: @JayBlanchard hi jay i am not getting any errors also though i have given to report errors, you see a lot of commenting also which i tried to test the variable value from the front end which is getting passed on but no sucess in connection

Comment: @chriz hi chriz PHPMyAdmin is running on my godaddy account and i have not myself installed PHP on my local machine, but another query is working fine with the same database